# Using Header propagation middleware (Microsoft.AspNetCore.HeaderPropagation) in a Function App

Tags: azure, function, http-headers, middleware, .net-7.0

I am currently working on a Timer-Triggered Isolated Process Function App targeting .Net 7.0, and am having some difficulties getting Header Propogation configured.

I followed the code example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#header-propagation-middleware

but couldn't see where to add the 'app.UseHeaderPropagation();' in my Function App program.cs class.

My code so far:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
        services.AddAccessTokenManagement(options =>
        {
            options.Client.Clients.Add("identityserver", new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
            {
                Address = PropertyRetrieve.GetPropertyValue("AccessTokenUrl"),
                ClientId = PropertyRetrieve.GetPropertyValue("ClientID"),
                ClientSecret = PropertyRetrieve.GetPropertyValue("ClientSecret"),
                Scope = PropertyRetrieve.GetPropertyValue("Scope")
            }) ;
        }).ConfigureBackchannelHttpClient();

        services.AddHeaderPropagation(options =>
        {
            options.Headers.Add("ETag", "If-Match");
        });

        services.AddHttpClient("default", c =>
        {
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Coverys_XuberSync");
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", PropertyRetrieve.GetPropertyValue("XuberApi")[8..]);
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");

            c.BaseAddress = new Uri(PropertyRetrieve.GetPropertyValue("XuberApi"));
        }).AddClientAccessTokenHandler("identityserver")
        .AddHeaderPropagation();       
    })  
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

When I run this I get the following message:

> Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Failed, Id=9a9731b1-83aa-48d3-8c04-a8df658f46f6, Duration=6963ms)
> [2023-02-17T11:14:03.976Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.Function1. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
> Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The HeaderPropagationValues.Headers property has not been initialized. Register the header propagation middleware by adding 'app.UseHeaderPropagation()' in the 'Configure(...)' method. Header propagation can only be used within the context of an HTTP request.)

Please could you assist with initialising this middleware in a Function App.

I have tried to Use the Middleware in the 'ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults' function, but this does not work

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(builder =>
    {
        builder.UseMiddleware<HeaderPropagationMiddleware>();
    })
```

Error Message:

> CS0311: The type 'MicrosoftAspNetCoreHeaderPropagationHeaderPropagationMiddleware' cannot be used as type parameter 'T in the generic type or method
> 'MiddlewareWorkerApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseMiddleware (IFunctionsWorkerApplicationBuilder)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
> 'MicrosoftAspNetCoreHeaderPropagationHeaderPropagationMiddleware' to 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Middleware.lFunctionsWorkerMiddleware'.